# is possible to create 3 graph in two rows using matplot lib in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I want one table in the first row and in the second row two diagrams.

like :

[image]

how can I change the size of 1 ?

Comment: Yes, using gridspec

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html